# My program in Java compiles on the computer, but gives runtime error on the website URI

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java language and learn by the URI website (https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en). I wrote a simple program here:

```java
package uri_programs;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int A = scan.nextInt();
        int B = scan.nextInt();
        int SOMA = A + B;

        System.out.println("SOMA = " + SOMA);
    }
}
```

The program runs on my computer and functions well, but when I check it on the URI website(teaching website) it gives this Runtime error. What is my problem here?

The original task was to read two integer values, the variables A and B. After this, calculate the sum between them and assign it to the variable SOMA and write the value of this variable.

Input is:

The input file contains 2 integer numbers.

Output is:

Print the variable SOMA with all the capital letters, with a blank space before and after the equal signal followed by the corresponding value to the sum of A and B. Like all the problems, don't forget to print the end of line, otherwise you will receive "Presentation Error".

I'd be grateful if someone would help!

the error image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlLWv.png)

Comment: You said something about a runtime error? Does the web site give any response other than simply those two words?

Comment: @DavidConrad unfortunately, only these two words.

Comment: @DavidConrad I've added an image of an error, could you check it?

Comment: The problem might be the way you(or editor) are providing the input.

Comment: Well, that's quite unhelpful of them. Is the class supposed to be named `uri_programs.Main`? Do they have any sandbox where you can upload a test program for them to run? It seems strange to me that they would expect an underscore in a package name, which is unusual.

Comment: try this -   System.out.println("SOMA = " + String.valueOf(SOMA))

Comment: @YogeshKaushik that wouldn't produce different output.

Comment: @DavidConrad it was actually me, who created "uri_programs" package name, but the class "Main" was suggested by them. I guess they don't have a sandbox.  Maybe an error is connected with how I organized my project?

Comment: @YogeshKaushik I tried what you offered, still gave an error.

Comment: IMO this is a problem with the website. Try contacting their support.

Comment: @maryinherdeath - Your class code has a package. That package is a folder in your project which is on your computer and your class is in that package. Its likely that the website does not ask you to create packages/folders, or automatically create the one specified in your code. So, it complains because there is no package on the website. Remove the package statement and try.

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev thank you for your explanation! I've already solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The error is connected to how you organized the project. To solve the issue you need to remove the package statement.

The robot judge doesn't know the the entry point of your program is inside that package/folder named `uri_programs`. That's why you are getting a run time error.

[Here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/faqs/about/examples) is a list of sample programs in different languages on their website.

Comment: thank you, now it got accepted! But, it is strange, because earlier I've already tried deleting the package name, but still got an error.

Comment: @maryinherdeath I am glad that it is solved. I'd appreciate it if you accept my answer by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: sorry, forgot about this.